# Problema con selector react

Tags: reactjs

tengo un problema que al cambiar el valor de un select en react, luego de guardarse en el state el nuevo valor este ultimo no me cambia en el selector. Antes en option ocupaba un evento on click para seleccionar el objeto que me retornaba en el map, pero el select con el onClick no funcionaba con chrome y se dejo con un onChange y un value en el option que toma el objeto

```
renderCareerSelector = () => {
    const { careers, selectedCareer } = this.state;
    
    return(
      <div className='create-course-selector-container' dataTapDisabled="true">
        <select className='language-selector' onChange={this.onSelectCareer} value={selectedCareer}>
          {careers.map((career, ix) => {
            if(career.role_id === 3) {
              return(
                <option value={career.id} key={ix}>{career.name}</option>
              )
            }
            return null
          })}
        </select>
      </div>
    )
  }

  onSelectCareer = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    console.log('llega ', value)
    const { careers } = this.state;
    const careerId = value;
    careers.map((career, ix) => {
      if(career.id === careerId) {
        this.setState({
          selectedCareer: career.name,
          selectedCareerId: career.id
        });
      }
    })
  };
```

Comment: ¿Estás usando react con clases o  con hooks? Luce un poco extraño tu código. ¿Esos métodos están dentro de una clase?

Comment: Hola, clases. SelectedCareer es null

Comment: Po otro lado ¿El id de la carrera es un número o es un string? Si es un número esta comparación `career.id === careerId` no va a funcionar, porque `target.value` es un `string`.

Comment: Ambos un string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el `select`, elimina el fragmento `value={selectedCareer}` y coloca el `option`:

```
...
return(
 <option value={career.id} selected={this.state.selectedCareer===career.id} key={ix}>{career.name}</option>
)
...
```

Eso debería funcionar. Te adjunto un ejemplo mínimo verificable que reproduje con tu código. Puedes ejecutarlo desde acá para que veas que funciona:

```js
const { Component }  = React;

class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return this.renderCareerSelector();
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            careers: [
                { id: "1", name: "A", role_id: 3 },
                { id: "2", name: "B", role_id: 3 },
                { id: "3", name: "C", role_id: 3 },
                { id: "4", name: "D", role_id: 3 }
            ],
            selectedCareer: null
        };
        this.onSelectCareer = this.onSelectCareer.bind(this);
    }

    renderCareerSelector = () => {
        const { careers, selectedCareer } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className='create-course-selector-container' >
                <select className='language-selector' onChange={this.onSelectCareer}>
                    {careers.map((career, ix) => {
                        if (career.role_id === 3) {
                            return (
                                <option selected={this.state.selectedCareer===career.id} value={career.id} key={ix}>{career.name}</option>
                            )
                        }
                        return null
                    })}
                </select>
            </div>
        )
    }

    onSelectCareer = ({ target: { value } }) => {
        const { careers } = this.state;
        const careerId = value;
        careers.forEach((career, ix) => {
            if (career.id === careerId) {
                this.setState({
                    selectedCareer: career.name,
                    selectedCareerId: career.id
                });
            }
        })
    };
}



ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Hola gracias por la ayuda, estaba viendo si está solución funciona también en safari

Comment: Yo acabo de ejecutarla desde un iphone sin problemas.

Comment: gracias totales